# Comparing integer variables in LUA

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I'm getting a very strange error, when trying to compare 2 integer variables using LUA on Corona SDK.

Basically this is what i have

```
**jAnswer** -- is a variable set via jSON, the value can only be 0 or 1.

    local function checkAnswer(answer)

       if (answer == jAnswer ) then
          print("Correct Answer")
          print("Answer is = "..answer.." jAnswer = "..jAnswer)
       else 
          print("Wrong Answer")
          print("Answer is = "..answer.." jAnswer = "..jAnswer)
       end

    end

checkAnswer(1) -- Calling the Function Here
```

Heres the problem, even if a get a output like "Answer is = 1, jAnswer = 1", i still get the "Wrong Answer".

Comment: [watch out for ponies](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/11/02/omg-ponies-aka-humanity-epic-fail/)

Comment: Please don't confuse between [Lua](https://github.com/LuaDist/lua) and [LUA](https://github.com/mniip/lua). Both languages are different. "Lua" is a name, and means "Moon" in Portugese. Please **do not write** it as _"LUA"_, which is both ugly and confusing, because then it becomes an acronym with [different meanings](http://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/lua) for different people.

Answer (score 4):

Basically, the jAnswer, was being seen as a String, so i just needed to convert the string to number, using a global class on lua named `tonumber()`

```
jAnswer = tonumber(jAnswer, 10) -- Convert using the decimal base
```

Thanks!